# using set! to change the value of a variable in drscheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to delete an occurrence of some value in a binary search tree. This is what I have so far:

```
(define removeBin (lambda (x t)
       (cond ((< x (car t)) (removeBin x (cadr t)))
             ((> x (car t)) (removeBin x (caddr t)))
             ((equal? x (car t)) 
                   (if(and (null? (cadr t)) (null? (caddr t))) '()
                (let ((r (replacement t))) ((set! (car t) r) (removeBin r t))))))))
```

It's giving me the following error: *set!: not an identifier in: (car t)*
What does that mean? and how can I fix it so that set! would work?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message explains, `(car t)` is not a valid identifier, and thus its value cannot be changed.

You need to use `set-car!` like this:

```
(set-car! t r)
```

This changes the `car` of `t` to `r`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I've tried what you said but it's still giving me an error: reference to undefined identifier: set-car!

Comment: @user: it seems that your Scheme implementation has removed it, hope this is useful: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.scheme/browse_thread/thread/19f7de0580e5117a

Answer (score 2):

In Racket there are "mutable pairs" that you get with `mcons`, access with `mcar` and `mcdr`, and mutate with `set-mcar!` and `set-mcdr!`.  You can get them using the conventional names if you're using one of the standard scheme languages, for example, by starting your code with `#lang r5rs`.