# Binary Search Tree Scheme

Tags: insert, tree, scheme, binary-search-tree, subtree

My friend and I are currently working on creating a Binary Search Tree in Scheme.  We cannot get it to save what we have inserted.  My professor said we are to use set-car! (cdr ( for the left subtree somehow, but I don't know where exactly to put it in.  We are supposed to use set-car! (cddr (  for the right subtree also.

We have done all of this so far correctly, but we just need help making it save our inserted nodes.

Code:

```
(define make-empty-BST '())

;create function to see if BST is empty
(define (emptyBST? BST) (null? BST))

;make non-empty BST with explicit list implementation
(define (make-BST root left-subtree right-subtree)  
  (list root left-subtree right-subtree))

;helper get root function
(define (getRoot BST) (car BST))

;helper get left subtree function
(define (getLeftsubTree BST) (cadr BST))   ;(car (cdr tr))

;helper get right subtree function
(define (getRightsubTree BST) (caddr BST))  ;(car (cdr (cdr tr)))

;Checks to see if a leaf is empty
(define (emptyleaf? BST) (and (null? (getLeftsubTree BST)) (null? (getRightsubTree BST))))

;inserts an item into the BST
(define (BST-insert BST item)
  (cond
    ((emptyBST? BST) ;if empty, create a new root with given item - use empty lists for left and right subtrees
     (make-BST item make-empty-BST make-empty-BST))
    ((< item (getRoot BST)) ;if item less than root, add to left subtree
     (make-BST (getRoot BST)
               (BST-insert (getLeftsubTree BST) item) ;recursion
               (getRightsubTree BST)))                                     
    ((> item (getRoot BST))                                         
     (make-BST (getRoot BST)
           (getLeftsubTree BST)
           (BST-insert (getRightsubTree BST) item)))
    (else BST)))  ; it's already in BST, do nothing
```

Comment: This is using Dr. Racket and R5RS.

Comment: At the moment, your BST-insert is returning a new tree that shares structure with the old tree, rather than updating the existing tree.  Do you see why? You should only create a new tree node at the leaf, and should only be assigning the left or right child of its parent.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Insert node key and value in binary search tree using scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12910579/1281433)? [using set! to change the value of a variable in drscheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4416862/1281433) is sort of relevant, too (though not high quality).

Comment: It's very difficult to read code in comments, so I'm not really going to try.  It's also not a great idea to edit the code in your question (although you could add _more_ code to it, if you wanted), because it invalidates answers to you question that mention some particular code.  At any rate, I've added an answer that I hope will help.

Comment: You might enjoy the binary search tree I did at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/03/05/binary-search-tree/). It uses Scheme, but instead of modifying the existing tree, as your professor suggests, it returns a newly-allocated tree at each step, sharing common nodes within the tree. That won't help you directly with your assignment, but it will give you a different perspective on what you are doing, and may help you identify what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since this sounds like an assignment, I don't want to provide the exact code that you need, but I'll show two functions that could be said to replace the nth element of list. The first will be analogous to yours, in that it returns a new list and doesn't modify the input list.  The second will modify the input list.

```
(define (replace-nth n element list)
  ;; return a new list like list, but whose 
  ;; nth element is element
  (if (= n 0)
      (cons element (cdr list))
      (cons (car list) (replace-nth (- n 1) element (cdr list)))))

(let ((l (list 1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (display (replace-nth 3 'x l)) ; prints (1 2 3 x 5 6)
  (display l))                   ; prints (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

The first returns a new list, but doesn't modify the input list.  It creates a new list using `cons` applied to part of the old list and some new value.  This is similar to what you're doing when you insert by creating a new tree that has the new value.  The tree that you've passed in won't have it, but the tree will.

```
(define (set-nth! n element list)
  ;; set the nth element of list to be element
  (if (= n 0)
     (set-car! list element)
     (set-nth! (- n 1) element (cdr list))))

(let ((l (list 1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (display (set-nth! 4 'x l)) ; prints #<void>
  (display l))                ; prints (1 2 3 4 x 6)
```

The second modifies the list that is passed to it.  Its return value isn't quite so important, because the structure passed into it actually gets modified.  This is more like what you'd want to do with your insert function.  You need to recurse until you get to the correct node in the tree, and the set its left or right child to be a new tree containing just the new element.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided 'get' procedures, why not start by providing a 'set' procedure?  Doing so works towards completing your 'tree/node abstraction' and gives you a base set of functions to try to use in your 'insert' procedure.

```
(define (setLeftsubTree BST left) 
  (set-car! (cdr BST) left))

(define (setRightsubTree BST right) 
  (set-car! (cddr BST) right))
```

Now, in your `insert` code, when you want to 'go left' but there is no left, call setLeftsubTree with a newly created leaf node.